# Multi-tenant website with high security requirements - possible configurations?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, multi-tenant

We are building a multi-tenant system for hundreds rather than thousands of separate tenants, with high data security requirements. At the moment, the plan is to go for:

- Isolated databases (one per tenant)
- Website and application pool (one per tenant), running under a unique identity, which is the only identity with access to the corresponding database.
- Separate physical directory structure per tenant

Obviously rolling out updates will need to be fully automated to keep on top of this, probably using MS Deploy + PowerShell scripts, and deployed one tenant at a time.

Are we creating a maintenance nightmare going this route? Are there other possible configurations we should be evaluating in this scenario, that might minimize our administrative overhead without sacrificing the security aspect?

Thanks!

Comment: Its not multi-tenant if they are separate websites.

Comment: @StingyJack it's the same product / website. So potentially we could keep them as a single physical file system and a single website on the server, but with isolated databases. But - having a separate memory space and user identity - gives us extra security, potentially. And having the same physical file system, but multiple databases could become problematic when deploying updates, perhaps? Hence the question!

Comment: How do the security requirements relate to multi-tenancy?  What do you need beyond, for each pair of tenants, Alice and Chuck, "Chuck cannot gain knowledge about, affect changes to, or deny access to Alice's data solely by using/abusing Chuck's application"?

Comment: @MikeSamuel they don't. I was more trying to provide some limited context as to why why we're likely to sit at the completely separate website/db end, rather than at the shared db/single website front end. The security requirement is purely restricting access to data - I would say there's limited risk/need in our area in terms of abusing other tenants in order to deny them access.

Comment: mike/stingy - very happy to rephrase the question if you think I can make it clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing would indeed be a very secure way of doing things, but it seems like there would be a lot of overhead involved.  One thing to consider is how to deal with logins.  Is each user required to specify TenantId, UserName and Password?  Or were you possibly going to assign each Tenant a unique sub-domain?

As far as maintenance is concerned, the best way to handle things is to cram as many teneants into a single web server / web farm and shove all of their data into a single relational db / db cluster.  That way, when you upgrade one customer, everybody gets upgraded.  At some point, you will have to buy another web farm / db cluster to put more tenants on, but you would be suprised how far 1 instance can go.

The exception to this rule is of course the sites like Google and Facebook who have too many users and too much data for the traditional relational dbs.  But for 95%+ of sites, I belive this model can work.

As far as security goes, you can add a TenantId to each and every table in your db and filter by it on **every query**.  Yes, this is non-trivial, but neither are the maintenance routines you describe.

Comment: Thanks dana - I'm very conscious of the admin overhead here... I guess I'm kinda hoping someone else who has done it will come along and say they've made it work well! Having a system that is more inherently secure is valuable to our client base, as we're up against on-site desktop software where there's much more limited chance of external data breaches. In terms of logins, yes - the most likely scenario would be subdomain-per-tenant and a wildcard SSL.

Comment: The major area of concern is rolling out deployments - obviously needing a high degree of confidence in our automation. But do we attempt to roll out to all databases at once, and upgrade a single file system structure? or roll one at a time so we can skip tenants if there are any issues? Any thoughts would be very welcome!

Comment: The company I work for started out building apps in the fashion you describe, where each tenant gets their own website, db, and URL.  We decided that rather than go the route of building extensive deployment scripts, we modified the applications to support multiple tenants per instance.  With that said, I have learned some lessons.  The most import of which is to not let *any* customer talk you into customizing their instance of the application at code level.  Instead, all needed customizability and extensibility needs to be built into the application itself.

Comment: Oracle CRM OnDemand supports tenancy by using a system they call PODs.  Each POD has a unique url (https://secure-ausomx[pod-id].crmondemand.com/).  Each POD supports multiple tenants, however for high security situations you can pay extra to have your own POD (or even an on-premise install).  They have a scheduling system of sorts where cetain PODs get updated at a time.  For a while they were deploying 2x releases per year.  You would login to your POD and get a "Scheduled Updated" message.  There are a lot of logistics involved, but when you are Oracle you can afford it :)

Comment: As an FYI, there are at least some people out there who are in favor of the separate db approach. (http://ayende.com/blog/3497/multi-tenancy-the-physical-data-model).

"You usually have a master app that manages that, with the web app being able to request provisioning on new resources from the master app. There are rarely humans involved in the common case.

Note that I think that isolation is what you get from this, security is part of it, but isolation also include a lot more freedom to do per tenant actions"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to keep tenant A's hands off tenant B's data.

1. [Siloing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_silo) as you've described -- the machines that service tenant B refuse all network connections from machines dedicated to other tenants, and have separate physical drives, logs, etc.   Here the kinds of zero days you worry about are those dealing with network messages and trojans that try to infect your code updates, and any device that can eavesdrop on network messages between machines in a silo.
2. Encrypting all stored data -- instead of separate machines, you encrypt all data.  Typically this still requires siloing databases, but not file-systems or logs.  The zero days you worry about are those for 1, plus anything dealing with process boundaries, memory caches, file system jailing, and anything affecting communication with the tenant key store.  I don't have much experience with it, but I'm skeptical that it is an administrative win.
3. [Information flow analysis](http://slang.soe.ucsc.edu/cormac/papers/plas09.pdf) -- make sure that each piece of data is labelled.  All requests from a program that is servicing a request for tenant A is marked as A, and all programs that service requests for tenant A accept only messages marked with A and not with B.  This can be used for defense in depth on top of other schemes since it does not, by itself protect storage systems.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is indeed a way to do Multiple Tenants, but as already mentioned above that isn't the same as Multi-Tenant.  See the IBM Developerworks article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-multitenantsaas/index.html?ca=drs- for factors to consider.

1. Please consider how many tenants you will have and how many users each tenant will have on average.
2. If you are going to have a large number of tenants, then your model might become too expensive to maintain.  Ten Thousand Tenants, each with its own database, filesystem structures, etc. well good luck.
3. True Multi-Tenancy like Success Factors, SalesForce.com, NetSuite, etc. are successful primarily because they are Multi-Tenant, one code base, one database model, etc.  All Tenants access one large scale system and see isolated data.
4. An alternative to True Multi-Tenancy is virtualization, and with Virtualization such as VMWare you can have your cake and eat it too.  Each vmware image has all you need and can be instantiated on demand.  You can make one update to the code and deploy it when the image is instantiated.  It is going to be much more cost effective than the silos you envision now, but less so than True Multi-Tenancy.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response. Virtualization is something we're considering too - but I'm curious how you see that as being more cost effective than having multiple customers on the same OS, but on silos there? And wouldn't rolling out updates to the VMs be as complicated? Or are you assuming shared storage somewhere and you just replace the VM images?

Comment: Its a continuum, The most costly is of course separate servers for each tenant.  Next is multiple virtual servers on the same physical server.  Next is virtual servers in the cloud.  Next is true multi tenancy where the most sharing is done.  There are many fuzzy areas in between and that can only be determined most cost effective based on the needs of the application.